# mysql select xml символ между элементами нод

Tags: mysql, xml, select

Всем привет! 
подскажите есть структура xml:

```
some_tbl.xmldata='<a><b>foo</b><b>bar baz</b></a>'
```

согласно:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html

делаю

```
select ExtractValue(some_tbl.xmldata, '/a/b') as xml_b from some_tbl where 1
```

и получаю 'foo bar baz' с пробелом между элементами нод b.
Вопрос - можно ли сделать запрос, чтобы элементы были разделены например точкой с запятой.

Замена пробела обёрткой в replace() не получается - потому как в этом случае bar и baz будут разделены ';' 'foo;bar;baz', а требуется получить 'foo;bar baz'.

Answer (score 0):

Желаемый результат требует скрытого unpivot (преобразование одной записи в несколько), чего в MySQL не имеется. Придётся извращаться.

Вариант:

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING ';' FROM ExtractValue(REPLACE(some_tbl.xmldata, '</b>', ';</b>'), '/a/b')) as xml_b 
FROM some_tbl 
WHERE 1
```